# How can we build shape keys for protruding eyes?

Tags: modeling, rigging, shape-keys

I've been working on the same character for months and have finally come down to the part of facial rigging but I can't get it to close it's eyes using the shape keys, the character is simple and not an optimal design, just experimental:
[image]

since his eyes are protruding just using one shape key would not do the trick. So I tried to use a set of shape keys like so:
[image]

but when I add a second shape key as a turn point from there: the first problem arises that the object changes to it's basis shape rather than staying in key1:
[image]

so I started editing anyway to see if it works out, but blender just extrapolates key 1 instead when I inrease the value of slider 2:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what is happening here and how can I fix this, please?

Comment: Since the closing of an eyelid around an eye involves *rotation*, I think you're better off rigging them with bones. Also, since it appears you haven't modeled any eyelids and are just pulling down the skin above the eyes, modeling some eyelids would be the first step.

Comment: @Mentalist, I'm new to this. Are eyelids modelled or carved from the skin?In realistic rigs they look as if a part of the skin are they modelled seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the 'Apply Shape Keys in Edit Mode' button right after you make a new Shape Key, so that your shape key is based on the previously made shape key(s).
[image]

Also, depending on how your rig is going to be setup, you may have to change the shape keys to blend relative to the previous position, rather than 'Basis' in the blend section too.  But it depends on how you want your bone controls to drive the shape keys.

[image]

Comment: but it seems to edit the mesh we would have to set the slider value to one otherwise the mesh is uneditable.